# Buying a coin only available on Bittrex (also Poloniex)

Tags: wallet, verification, bittrex

## Is there an easier/alternative route to go about purchasing a currency that is only being traded on Bittrex?

After attempting the `basic verification`, I received an error saying that there was **NO PUBLIC RECORD MATCH** based on the information provided. Instead of offering an attempt at resubmitting, the only option is to go through their ***Enhanced Verification***. After submitting the required information (including various photo IDs), the process seems to be in limbo until the request is processed.

My concerns... Desired currency drastically increases in value. Bitcoin's value decreases while waiting. Bittrex decides to deny my enhanced verification submission.

Clarification and/or recommendations would be appreciated!

*~ **NOTE** ~ this is just the process to transfer BTC from coinbase. What can/should I expect when purchasing/withdrawing?!*

Comment: Did you take a selfie? I feel like most people who failed their enhanced verification either took picture of an ID-picture or used webcam in low-light circumstances. I have an enhanced account, never faced any problems with tradings or deposits/withdrawals.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Chak. Yeah, I took a selfie and I received a response saying that it was denied. In the response it was stated that there was not enough resemblance between my ID picture and the selfie..